# Keep the state of checkbox angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, local-storage

i have this multiple checkbox.

```
<div ng-repeat="setting in settings">
    <input type="checkbox" name="setting.name" ng-model="setting.value">{{setting.name}}
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.settings = [{
           name: 'OrderNr',
           value: ''
       }, {
           name: 'CustomerNr',
           value: ''
       }, {
           name: 'CatalogName',
           value: ''
       }, {
           name: 'OrderDate',
           value: ''
       }, {
           name: 'OrderState',
           value: ''
       }];
```

when i click the save button, i call this function for store data in local storage

```
$scope.saveSetting = function() {
    var json = angular.toJson($scope.settings);
    localStorageService.add('settings',json);

};
```

how can i keep my settings when i reload the page?

Answer (score 2):

What about using $cookies.

Have a look at [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/%24cookies)

Basically all you need to do is inject the service in the controller as a dependency and use it as an object.

In your controller:

```
$scope.saveSetting = function() {
    $cookies.settings = $scope.settings;
};
```

And to use them:

```
$scope.loadSetting = function() {
     $scope.settings = $cookies.settings;
};
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ngStorage directive. I use it in my app. You would simply set the settings to your storage using ngStorage and then also set the initial value for your settings via ngStorage when the controller loads.

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set $scope.settings when your controller loads.

```
var myCtrl = function($scope) {
    if(localStorage.settings) {
        $scope.settings = angular.fromJson(localStorage.settings);
    }
}
```